# "I know for sure" or "I know it for sure"?

Tags: grammar

Tell please which sentence is correct.

> I know for sure that he is right.
>
> I know it for sure that he is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "I know it for sure." *it* is the object of "know".

In "I know for sure that he is right", *that he is right* is the object of "know".

You can't have two grammatically independent direct objects in the same clause, so your second option is not grammatical.